# form control error on form submission in laravel app

Tags: laravel

on form submission, for some fields form-control error is working on one text area it is not working, this is description area + in control error i want to include that submitter should fill min 350 words or more. here is exact from blade template

**control error is working on this:**

```
 <div class="form-row mb-3">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="item_title" class="text-black">{{ __('backend.item.title') }}</label>
                                        <input id="item_title" type="text" class="form-control @error('item_title') is-invalid @enderror" name="item_title" value="{{ old('item_title') ? old('item_title') : $item->item_title }}">
                                        @error('item_title')
                                        <span class="invalid-tooltip">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                        @enderror
```

**control error is not working on this fill**

```
        <div class="form-row mb-3">

                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <label for="item_description" class="text-black">{{ __('backend.item.description') }}</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control @error('item_description') is-invalid @enderror" id="item_description" rows="5" name="item_description">{{ old('item_description') ? old('item_description') : $item->item_description }}</textarea>
                                        @error('item_description')
                                        <span class="invalid-tooltip">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

i applied the control but its not working

Comment: Does it show the error message ?

Comment: @xenooooo on @error('item_title') this error works, this @error('item_description') does not work

Comment: Try this first instead of `{{ old('item_description') ? old('item_description') : $item->item_description }}` , use `{{ old('item_description', $item->item_description) }}`

Comment: Also check your `validation rules` if its correct